# Return true if sub-list at given index is NOT null, false otherwise

Tags: java, arraylist, junit

I get AssertionError with my working out.

```
public boolean subListNullCheck (ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> list, int j) {
    if(list == null || list.isEmpty() || list.get(0).isEmpty() ) {
        return false;
                
    } if(list.contains(j)) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`list.contains(j)` returns `true` if that `list` contains the value `j`, not if the element at index `j` is not null.

You can write:

```
public boolean subListNullCheck (ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> list, int j) {
    if (list == null) {
        return false;             
    } else if (j >= 0 && list.size > j && list.get(j) != null) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Or simply

```
public boolean subListNullCheck (ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> list, int j) {
    return list != null && j >= 0 &&& list.size > j && list.get(j) != null;
}
```

Comment: i still get "java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 out of bounds for length 1"

Comment: @NicKOver are you passing negative `j` to the method? In that case, add a check that j >= 0.